# LinqToSQL 3.5 vs 4.0 - Any major difference?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Is there any major difference in the LinqToSQL engine in .NET 3.5 vs that in .NET 4.0, such as better query execution?

Comment: Check this article: [Changes to Linq to Sql in .NET 4](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40)

Comment: You mean _.Net_, not C#.